# Needing to convert array of user ids to ObjectIds to use in aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I was working on some old code using the aggregate framework.  The aggregate looks something like this:

```
User.aggregate([
  { $match: {
     _id: { $in: invitedUserObjectIds, $ne: game.createdBy._id },
    ...
  },
...
]
```

Originally the code had user ids in the form of strings like so `['qwertyuiop',...]`.  It was working.

Now in order to get it to work properly I have to convert each string id into an ObjectId before passing the new ObjectId array to the `$match` aggregate pipeline stage.

Not a big deal but trying to understand why this is or if I am missing something simple?  I've tested the exact same query with only `invitedUserObjectIds` changing to either array of string ids or array of object ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB query operators are type-sensitive.

In order to match properly, the data type of the argument in the query must match the data type of the field in the document stored in the database.

Query functions like `findById` in mongoose cast the passed argument to the type declared in the schema for the _id field.

An aggregation pipeline does not automatically cast the values, so you will need to build the array so it contains the proper data types for matching.